# Having trouble using a sync variable in Chapel during parallelization

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, synchronization, chapel

So, I am working on this project and I am writing in Chapel computing language. I already wrote the program and it works perfectly when run un-parallelized.

But then when I add the **`forall`** statements that I need to parallelize, the program does run a helluva lot faster but it doesn't provide the results I need. Which I know is because I have a race condition in steps 1, 3, 5 and 7 when I do `j = j - 1;` so I try and make `j` a synced variable to prevent this race condition from ruining my results and then I compile, and run and my program never makes it out of step 1, which is where the first synced variable is so I have reason to believe that it is because of the synced variable, `j`.

If anybody has any insight about how I should parallelize or sync instead so that my final mesh is sorted that would be great. Here's the code:

```
//SlideSort.chapel_version
//

use Random;
use Time;

config const seed = 2345;
var rs = new RandomStream(seed);
var num: int;
var transferMesh:[0..36530] int;
var copyMesh:[0..36530] int;
var mesh:[0..37883] int;
var i: int;
var z: int;



   proc slideSort(){
      writeln("\nSorting..\n");
/*-------------------------Step 1-------------------------------*/
      writeln("Step 1");
      forall i in 0..36530{
         transferMesh[i] = mesh[i+677];
      }//end for

      forall i in 0..1352{
         forall a in 0..26{
            var value: int = transferMesh[1353*a+i];
            var j$: int = 1353*a+i-1;
               while j$>= 1353*a && transferMesh[j$] > value{
                  transferMesh[j$+1] = transferMesh[j$];
                  j$ = j$ - 1;
               }//end While
               transferMesh[j$+1] = value;
         }//end a_for
      }//end i_for

      forall k in 0..36530{
         mesh[k+677] = transferMesh[k];
      }//end For_k
/*--------------------------Step 2--------------------------------*/
      writeln("Step 2");
         forall k in 677..37207{
            transferMesh[k-677] = mesh[k];
         }//end k_for

         forall k in 0..1352{
            for z in 0..26{
               copyMesh[k+1353*z] = transferMesh[27*k+z];
            }//end z_for
         }//end k_for

         forall k in 0..36530{
            mesh[k+677] = copyMesh[k];
         }//end k_for
/*--------------------------Step 3--------------------------------*/
      writeln("Step 3");
         forall i in 0..36530{
            transferMesh[i] = mesh[i+677];
         }//end for

         forall i in 0..1352{
            forall a in 0..26{
               var value: int = transferMesh[1353*a+i];
               var j: int = 1353*a+i-1;
                  while j>= 1353*a && transferMesh[j] > value{
                     transferMesh[j+1] = transferMesh[j];
                     j = j - 1;
                  }//end While
                  transferMesh[j+1] = value;
            }//end a_for
         }//end i_for

         forall k in 0..36530{
            mesh[k+677] = transferMesh[k];
         }//end For_k
/*--------------------------Step 4--------------------------------*/
      writeln("Step 4");
         forall k in 677..37207{
            transferMesh[k-677] = mesh[k];
         }//end for

         forall k in 0..1352{
            forall z in 0..26{
               copyMesh[27*k+z] = transferMesh[k+1353*z];
            }//end z_for
         }//end k_for

         forall k in 0..36530{
            mesh[k+677] = copyMesh[k];
         }//end k_for
/*--------------------------Step 5--------------------------------*/
      writeln("Step 5");
         forall i in 0..36530{
            transferMesh[i] = mesh[i+677];
         }//end for

         forall i in 0..1352{
            forall a in 0..26{
               var value: int = transferMesh[1353*a+i];
               var j: int = 1353*a+i-1;
                  while j>= 1353*a && transferMesh[j] > value{
                     transferMesh[j+1] = transferMesh[j];
                     j = j - 1;
                  }//end While
                  transferMesh[j+1] = value;
            }//end a_for
         }//end i_for

         forall k in 0..36530{
            mesh[k+677] = transferMesh[k];
         }//end For_k
/*--------------------------Step 6--------------------------------*/
      writeln("Step 6");
        /*This is the padding step, so, since I already have a padded array
          I will simply just sort my padded array in step 7
        */
/*--------------------------Step 7--------------------------------*/
      writeln("Step 7\n");
         forall k in 0..1352{
            forall a in 0..27{
               var value: int = mesh[1353*a+k];
               var j: int = 1353*a+k-1;
               while j >= 1353 *a && mesh[j] > value{
                  mesh[j+1] = mesh [j];
                  j = j - 1;
               }//end while
               mesh[j+1] = value;
            }//end a_for
         }//end k_for


   }//slideSort END
/*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^end slidesort^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/

   proc isSorted() :int{
      var sorted: int = 0;
      for i in 0..37882{
         if mesh[i+1] < mesh[i]{
            writeln("NOT SORTED :(");
            sorted = 1;
            break;
         }//if
      }//end For
      return sorted;
   }// isSorted END



proc main(){

/*Padding array with -INF*/
   for i in 0..676 do mesh[i] = -1000000;

/*Filling array with random ints*/
   for i in 677..37207{
      num = (301 * rs.getNext()): int;
      mesh[i] = num;
   }//end for

/*Padding array with +INF*/
   for i in 37208..37883 do mesh[i] = 1000000;


   writeln("\n200th Element: ", mesh[199],"\n1000th Element: ", mesh[999]);
   writeln("30000th Element: ", mesh[29999], "\n37300th Element: ", mesh[37299]);

   const startTime = getCurrentTime();
   slideSort();
   const endTime = getCurrentTime();

   writeln("\n200th Element: ", mesh[199], "\n1000th Element: ", mesh[999]);
   writeln("30000th Element: ", mesh[29999], "\n37300th Element: ", mesh[37299]);

   writeln("\n\nElapsed time was: ", (endTime - startTime));

   if(isSorted()==0) then writeln("\nYep the mesh is sorted via SlideSort :)");

   write("\nWould you like to print out every 100th element of the Mesh?\n",
           "'Y' for yes\n",
           "'N' for no\n");
   var print: string = "N";
   print = stdin.read(string);

   if print == "Y" || print == "y"{
      for i in 0..37883 by 100{
         write(mesh[i],"\n");
      }//end innerFor
   }//end if

}//end MAIN
```

Comment: And yes, I know j is not synced in my code that I posted, I was trying to find another solution before I had posted and forgot to put it back in. Anything helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have much to do with synced variables. Your double loops look like this :

```
forall i in 0..1352 do
    forall a in 0..26
    {
        var j = 1353*a+i;
        var v = transferMesh[j];

        while( j>= 1353*a )
        {
            if( transferMesh[j] <= v )
                break;

            transferMesh[j+1] = transferMesh[j];
            j--;
        }

        transferMesh[j+1] = v;
    }
```

This is an obvious source of data races. You test `transferMesh[j]`, but since another i with the same a can be iterating simultaneously, it could modify that value concurrently, leading to undefined results.

For each of these loops, you should allow only one worker per block (thus per value of a). Thus, you should iterate in parallel only over a, i.e. `forall a in 0..26 do for i in 0..1352 {...}`

---

The corrected code is thus easily obtained :

```
//SlideSort.chapel_version
//

use Random;
use Time;

config const seed = 2345;
var rs = new RandomStream(seed);
var num: int;
var transferMesh:[0..36530] int;
var copyMesh:[0..36530] int;
var mesh:[0..37883] int;
var i: int;
var z: int;



proc slideSort()
{
  writeln("\nSorting..\n");
  /*-------------------------Step 1-------------------------------*/
  writeln("Step 1");
  forall i in 0..36530
  {
    transferMesh[i] = mesh[i+677];
  }//end for

  forall a in 0..26
  {
    for i in 0..1352
    {
      var value: int = transferMesh[1353*a+i];
      var j: int = 1353*a+i-1;
      while j>= 1353*a && transferMesh[j] > value
      {
        transferMesh[j+1] = transferMesh[j];
        j = j - 1;
      }//end While
      transferMesh[j+1] = value;
    }//end i_for
  }//end a_for

  forall k in 0..36530
  {
    mesh[k+677] = transferMesh[k];
  }//end For_k
  /*--------------------------Step 2--------------------------------*/
  writeln("Step 2");
  forall k in 677..37207
  {
    transferMesh[k-677] = mesh[k];
  }//end k_for

  forall z in 0..26
  {
    forall k in 0..1352
    {
      copyMesh[k+1353*z] = transferMesh[27*k+z];
    }//end k_for
  }//end z_for

  forall k in 0..36530
  {
    mesh[k+677] = copyMesh[k];
  }//end k_for
  /*--------------------------Step 3--------------------------------*/
  writeln("Step 3");
  forall i in 0..36530
  {
    transferMesh[i] = mesh[i+677];
  }//end for

  forall a in 0..26
  {
    for i in 0..1352
    {
      var value: int = transferMesh[1353*a+i];
      var j: int = 1353*a+i-1;
      while j>= 1353*a && transferMesh[j] > value
      {
        transferMesh[j+1] = transferMesh[j];
        j = j - 1;
      }//end While
      transferMesh[j+1] = value;
    }//end i_for
  }//end a_for

  forall k in 0..36530
  {
    mesh[k+677] = transferMesh[k];
  }//end For_k
  /*--------------------------Step 4--------------------------------*/
  writeln("Step 4");
  forall k in 677..37207
  {
    transferMesh[k-677] = mesh[k];
  }//end for

  forall k in 0..1352
  {
    for z in 0..26
    {
      copyMesh[27*k+z] = transferMesh[k+1353*z];
    }//end z_for
  }//end k_for

  forall k in 0..36530
  {
    mesh[k+677] = copyMesh[k];
  }//end k_for
  /*--------------------------Step 5--------------------------------*/
  writeln("Step 5");
  forall i in 0..36530
  {
    transferMesh[i] = mesh[i+677];
  }//end for

  forall a in 0..26
  {
    for i in 0..1352
    {
      var value: int = transferMesh[1353*a+i];
      var j: int = 1353*a+i-1;
      while j>= 1353*a && transferMesh[j] > value
      {
        transferMesh[j+1] = transferMesh[j];
        j = j - 1;
      }//end While
      transferMesh[j+1] = value;
    }//end i_for
  }//end a_for

  forall k in 0..36530
  {
    mesh[k+677] = transferMesh[k];
  }//end For_k
  /*--------------------------Step 6--------------------------------*/
  writeln("Step 6");
  /*This is the padding step, so, since I already have a padded array
    I will simply just sort my padded array in step 7
   */
  /*--------------------------Step 7--------------------------------*/
  writeln("Step 7\n");
  forall a in 0..27
  {
    for k in 0..1352
    {
      var value: int = mesh[1353*a+k];
      var j: int = 1353*a+k-1;
      while j >= 1353 *a && mesh[j] > value
      {
        mesh[j+1] = mesh [j];
        j = j - 1;
      }//end while
      mesh[j+1] = value;
    }//end k_for
  }//end a_for


}//slideSort END
/*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^end slidesort^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/

proc isSorted() :int
{
  var sorted: int = 0;
  for i in 0..37882
  {
    if mesh[i+1] < mesh[i]
    {
      writeln("NOT SORTED :(");
      sorted = 1;
      break;
    }//if
  }//end For
  return sorted;
}// isSorted END



proc main()
{

  /*Padding array with -INF*/
  for i in 0..676 do mesh[i] = -1000000;

  /*Filling array with random ints*/
  for i in 677..37207
  {
    num = (301 * rs.getNext()): int;
    mesh[i] = num;
  }//end for

  /*Padding array with +INF*/
  for i in 37208..37883 do mesh[i] = 1000000;


  writeln("\n200th Element: ", mesh[199],"\n1000th Element: ", mesh[999]);
  writeln("30000th Element: ", mesh[29999], "\n37300th Element: ", mesh[37299]);

  const startTime = getCurrentTime();
  slideSort();
  const endTime = getCurrentTime();

  writeln("\n200th Element: ", mesh[199], "\n1000th Element: ", mesh[999]);
  writeln("30000th Element: ", mesh[29999], "\n37300th Element: ", mesh[37299]);

  writeln("\n\nElapsed time was: ", (endTime - startTime));

  if(isSorted()==0) then writeln("\nYep the mesh is sorted via SlideSort :)");

}//end MAIN
```

Result :

```
$ chpl sort.chpl ; ./a.out | tail -n 1
Yep the mesh is sorted via SlideSort :)
```